# Not able to update page number in TOC of document using docx4j

Tags: java, maven, bookmarks, docx4j, tableofcontents

While generating Table of content , i am not able to update page number.
It shows the exception as "Encountered broken bookmarks; not configured to remediate."
I used the below code to update TOC ..

TocGenerator tocGenerator = new TocGenerator(wordMLPackage);

tocGenerator.generateToc( 0, " TOC \o \"1-3\" \h \z \u ", false);

tocGenerator.updateToc( false);

Answer (score 0):

The message is coming from here:

```
/**
 * Calculate page numbers
 * 
 * @return
 * @throws TocException
 */
private Map<String, Integer> getPageNumbersMap() throws TocException {

    // @since 6.1, check bookmarks are ok first
    // what to do if not ok?
    // - default behaviour is to fail
    // - but can be configured to remediate:
    boolean remediate = Docx4jProperties.getProperty("docx4j.toc.BookmarksIntegrity.remediate", false);

    // 
    BookmarksIntegrity bm = new BookmarksIntegrity();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    bm.setWriter(sw);
    BookmarksStatus result = null;
    try {
        // Checks are performed on all bookmarks, not just those with
        // a name of the form "_Toc*".  We don't check for missing _Toc bookmarks.
        result = bm.check(wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart(), remediate);
    } catch (Exception e) { /* won't happen */}
    if (result==BookmarksStatus.BROKEN) {
        throw new TocException("Encountered broken bookmarks; not configured to remediate. \n" + sw.toString());
    }

    if (Docx4J.pdfViaFO()) {
        return getPageNumbersMapViaFOP();
    } else {
        // recommended
        return getPageNumbersMapViaService();
    }
}
```

Please note that unless you are an existing licensee of Plutext's PDF Converter service, you won't be able to use getPageNumbersMapViaService().

For a possible alternative approach, please see https://www.docx4java.org/blog/2020/03/documents4j-for-toc-update/ which builds upon https://www.docx4java.org/blog/2020/03/documents4j-for-pdf-output/